# CSS transform function order

Tags: css

Why is there a difference in output between:

```
transform: translate(0, 100px) scale(2, 2);
```

and

```
transform: scale(2, 2) translate(0, 100px);
```

?

The first statement does what you (I) expect. Move the element 100px down and double the size. The second statement doubles the size, but also doubles the translate, so the element is moved down 200px!

Comment: Thinking some more... I could probably explain this behaviour if transform-origin was set to 0 0, because than, the element is moved, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#scale())

Comment: Forget the above comment. The element is not 'moved' when transform-origin is set to 0 0. (I had a text-align: center on the element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `transform` will change the current coordinates system step by step (from left to right). That means each transform will change the coordinates system accumulatively. For this case:

```
transform: scale(2, 2) translate(0, 100px);
```

firstly the `scale(2,2)` will change the coordinates system by this formula:

```
X2 = X1 * 2
Y2 = Y1 * 2
```

Next when the `translate(0, 100px)` is applied, we have:

```
X2 = (X1 + 0) * 2 = X1 * 2
Y2 = (Y1 + 100) * 2 = Y1 * 2 + 200 (now you see 100px is doubled to 200px).
```

Similarly for the first case:

```
transform: translate(0, 100px) scale(2, 2);
```

You can derive that the formulas should be:

```
X2 = X1 + 0
Y2 = Y1 + 100
```

and

```
X2 = (X1 * 2) + 0 = X1 * 2
Y2 = (Y1 * 2) + 100 = Y1 * 2 + 100
```