# Rotate element on mousemove that's larger than viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having an issue trying to rotate an element on mousemove. I believe the issue is related to the fact that my element is much larger than the screen (set in CSS with vh/vw units) but essentially the element sound rotate, from the centre on mousemove.

I have set up a jsFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/cLx290p1/

```
function themeLanding() {
    var graphic = $('.landing-2016');
    if (graphic.length > 0) {
        var offset = graphic.offset();
        function mouse(evt) {
            var centerX = (offset.left) + (graphic.width()/2),
            centerY = (offset.top) + (graphic.height()/2),
            mouseX = evt.pageX,
            mouseY = evt.pageY,
            radians = Math.atan2(mouseX - centerX, mouseY - centerY);
            degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
            graphic.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg) translate(-50%,-50%)');
            graphic.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg) translate(-50%,-50%)');
            graphic.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg) translate(-50%,-50%)');
            graphic.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg) translate(-50%,-50%)');
            graphic.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg) translate(-50%,-50%)');
        }
        $(document).mousemove(mouse);
    }
}
themeLanding();
```

I have also applied the same idea, without mousemove as a debugging check, to rotate the same element using CSS3.

https://jsfiddle.net/psywr840/1/

This seems to work fine so I am unsure where I am going wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using css `transform` functions, the functions are processed in order from left to right.

In your case, what you want is to first `translate` the element and THEN `rotate` it. For example this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25305203/2661226) explains something similar, only instead of rotate they use scale, but the principle is the same.

So what you want, is to change the order of transform functions:

```
graphic.css('-moz-transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
graphic.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
graphic.css('-o-transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
graphic.css('-ms-transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
graphic.css('transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
```

Comment: I just figured this out too. Whhhhhyy?? Thanks so much for clearing this up also but this seems a bit crazy?

Comment: It's not that crazy, its actually pretty useful. For example if you wanted to rotate element using it's center point and then the resulted rotated element translate again to some different place, than you wouldn't be able to achieve this without order. Because what you have to do in situation like this is `translate`, `rotate` and than again `translate`.